# Can Phantasmal Force be used to create an illusion that a person is made of lava?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

One of my players in my dungeons and dragons fifth edition game wants to try using Phantasmal force to create an illusion that he is made of lava to stop creatures from touching him. I wasn't sure if that is something the spell is able to do even when reading through the description.

Comment: At first I thought you were asking if you could cast _Phantasmal Force_ and have a person believe that **they** have become lava, but then I realized you meant the **caster**. It's still pretty great, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

> On a failed save, you create a phantasmal object, creature, or **other visible phenomenon** of your choice that is **no larger than a 10-foot cube** and that is perceivable only to the target for the duration. *(Emphasis mine)*

A body-shaped mass of lava definitely counts as a 'visible phenomenon' (which is almost an all-encompassing term anyway). The character can certainly fit inside a '10-foot cube', so that requirement is met. If you were unsure as to whether the illusion could occupy space already taken up by the caster themselves, then they could simply create an illusion of a lava body covering, just outside the skin, bypassing that problem.

The player could even argue that the d6 damage per round could be perceived as lava flying from their body, and onto the creature, although you may want to disallow that.

Comment: Wouldn't the damage just be because of the extreme heat?

Comment: Doesn't really matter why, just matters if the target is within the 10' surrounding you.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, they can, against one target only. As seen in the spell description (PHB p264):

> While a target is affected by the spell, ***the target treats the
>   phantasm as if it were real. The target rationalizes any illogical
>   outcomes from interacting with the phantasm.*** For example. a target
>   attempting to walk across a phantasmal bridge that spans a chasm falls
>   once it steps onto the bridge. If the target survives the fall, it
>   still believes that the bridge exists and comes up with some other
>   explanation for its fall-it was pushed, it slipped, or a strong wind
>   might have knocked it off.
>
> Similarly, a phantasm created to appear as fire, a pool of acid, or
>   ***lava*** can burn the target. Each round on your turn. the phantasm can
>   deal 1d6 psychic damage to the target if it is in the phantasm's area
>   or within 5 feet of the phantasm, provided that the illusion is of a
>   creature or hazard that could logically deal damage, such as by
>   attacking. The target perceives the damage as a type appropriate to
>   the illusion.

Comment: Although it would just be 1 Creature you could target it in this way - not all. And if you move, then you step out of the "lava".

Comment: Simply copy-pasting the spell text without any argument is quite useless.

Comment: I also downvoted due to the lack of addressing the actual question. In addition, this answer does not address the fact that Phantasmal Force only affects a single creature, so the OP question about keeping **creatures** (plural) away is not addressed here.

Comment: @Olorin It doesn't need an argument. The answer is there. There is no room for misinterpretation.

Comment: If the answer was so clear then the OP would not have asked. He already read and knows what the spell text says, and still he's looking for an answer. Yours is not helping him with anything.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli amended to included that distinction.